# Error (Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I am getting this error as JSON result.error. While my JSON is an valid one, check it on JSON vaildator online.

This is my code for JSON request.

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters, encoding:.JSON)
                .responseJSON { (request, response, result) in
                    hud.hide(true)
                    // Set flag to disale poor internet connection alert
                    weakInternet = false
                    print(result.error)
                    if (result.value != nil) {
                        print("API Response: \(result.value!)")
                        // Pass the response JSON to the completion block
                        completion(json: result.value!)
                    } else {
                        // Response JSON is NULL
                    }
            }
```

When i hit the same service with particular request parameters i am getting this response.

```
{"error":"success","post_data":{"first_name":"hd","last_name":"df","email":"hiiaaaaaaa@dnsa.coma","password":"himanshu","confirm_password":"himanshu","companies":["Big Rattle Technologies_Fg_yes"],"institutes":[""]},"msg":"success","data":{"_id":"5742ae1564b35e37369f0838","first_name":"hd","last_name":"df","email":"hiiaaaaaaa@dnsa.coma","profile_pic":"","loc":[0,0],"locs":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[0,0]},"institutes":[],"companies":[{"comapny_id":"555b2d0a678e79ed510041ce","group_id":"556c2434678e79a1820041dd","name":"Big Rattle Technologies","designation":"Fg","is_current":"yes"}],"device_token":"","user_group":"site_user","is_verified":0,"is_disclose":1,"is_discover":1,"wallNotification":1,"messageNotification":1,"matchNotification":1,"verificationSent":0,"status":1,"mobile":"","linkedin_id":"","facebook_id":"","os":"","qblox_id":12957726,"updated_at":"2016-05-23 07:15:33","created_at":"2016-05-23 07:15:33","current_company":"Big Rattle Technologies"}}
```

Anybody knows what is the problem in my case?

Comment: Try the `.responseString { response in
             print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
         }` instead of `responseJSON` to see what the result looks like.

Comment: `Invalid value around character 0` Your response is not valid JSON.

Comment: But, i checked the postman response of service on online json viewer and it's showing that the response is valid one.

Comment: Me also got the same error, because of my response in not valid JSON formate. It's DOCTYPE is html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an issue with my web service. They are giving me the response in "text/HTML" format rather than HTML. When i printed my response on debugger then i got:

```
"Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
```

Now, i updated my webservice and everything is working like a charm.

Comment: where did you include this?

Comment: in my webservice response.

Comment: how u solve ur issue from your app webservice code or backend php web service changes

Answer (score 2):

I am getting same error last time because there will be problem is web service returns me response in array and i am trying to convert its into dictionary and extract its value.

Check Your web service response.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5, Swift 4

```
var headers = HTTPHeaders()
    headers = [
        "Content-Type" :"text/html; charset=UTF-8",
        //"Content-Type": "application/json",
        //"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        //"Accept": "application/json",
        "Accept": "multipart/form-data"
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when using the **wrong** Firebase Server key to send a remote push notification.

Go to `Firebase` > `Project Overview` > `CogIcon` > `Project Settings` > `Cloud Messaging` > `Server Key`

[image]

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send") else { return }    

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = try?

let paramDict = [String:Any]() // this has values
JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: paramDict, options: [])
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let serverKey = "firebase server key" // *** SERVER KEY USED HERE ***
request.setValue("key=\(serverKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)  { (data, response, error) in

    do {
        if let jsonData = data {
                    
            if let jsonDataDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                print("jsonData Successfully Sent data: \n\(jsonDataDict))")
            }
        }
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print("jsonData Error: \(err.debugDescription)")
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure The firewall Off from Server